# Засунуть в бд значения, полученные через get-запрос

Tags: python, requests, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Я получаю данные с сайта с помощью get-запроса, они выводятся вот в таком формате:

```
"[{\"id\":150290,\"answer\":\"deciduous\",\"question\":\"\",\"value\":null}]"
```

После этого нужно взять из этой конструкции значение параметра id и засунуть его в базу данных с помощью SQLAlchemy. Не могу понять, как это сделать, буду рада любой помощи.

Структура базы данных:

```
class Post(DeclarativeBase):
__tablename__ = 'new_table'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
question_text = Column('question_text', String)
answer_text = Column('answer_text', String)
date = Column(DateTime)
```

Comment: Подклюсться к БД, "засунуть "значения"", отключиться от БД. )) А если серьезно, то экстасенсов здесь нет, свой код, тип бд, структуру таблицы куда собираетесь "засунуть" данные, "в студию" (в вопрос тоесть) пожалуйста

Comment: добавила, спасибо за замечание

Comment: А в чем собственно возникла сложность? Вы знете как из текстового json (коим является Ваша строка) сделать словарь? Вы знаете как забрать значение из словаря по ключу?

Comment: Строго говоря из Вашего `json` получится список словарей, но никто же нам не мешает взять из него нужный элемент к примеру по индексу, к примеру с индексом 0. Или может быть Вам этот json в видк строки "как есть" записать в БД нужно?

Comment: когда я обращаюсь по data[0] мне выдается только первый символ строки, я совсем не понимаю, как получить доступ именно к элементам словаря, находящихся в списке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import json
js = "[{\"id\":150290,\"answer\":\"deciduous\",\"question\":\"\",\"value\":null}]"
data = json.loads(js)
print(data[0])

print(
    data[0].get('id')
)

#  или
data, *_ = json.loads(js)
print(data)

print(
    data.get('id')
)
```

```latex
{'id': 150290, 'answer': 'deciduous', 'question': '', 'value': None}
150290
{'id': 150290, 'answer': 'deciduous', 'question': '', 'value': None}
150290
```

#### UPD

```py
import requests
url = 'your_url'

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.json()

print(
   data[0].get('id')
)
```

Comment: а если я получаю данные из объекта response? выдает ошибку - "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response"

Comment: @jiezzzzzzzzz, добавил. попробуйте